Is it possible to modify a search URL so that the results are interpreted as English?
I am using the web app webtopdf.com which converts web pages, based on URLs you supply, to PDFs.
The URL I'm providing is a Google Search which I see in English https://www.google.com/search?q=Bible but webtopdf.com always saves it to PDF in Korean.
Is it possible to modify the Google Search URL so the PDF is saved in English?
 


Specify the interface language (host language) as English in the URL you submit to webtopdf.com by appending &hl=en.
www.google.com/search?q=bible&hl=en

Additional Resources

Google Search request parameters
Interface Language

The hl parameter
Supported values




Thanks. what does hl stand for? Is there a list of keys and values?

It stands for host/interface language. I've updated the answer to include more detail and some links to Google resources.
